# Rails rake assets:precompile for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, assets

I'm trying to precompile the assets for my app to deploy to Heroku but have to following error.

When running:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Error:

```
/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Because I use in development SQLite and in production Postgresql the following Gemfile

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.1.0"

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha.0'
  gem 'html5-boilerplate'
end
```

I tried a lot but can't get this working.

I don't know if this is important but my database.yml looks like:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: db
  encoding: unicode
  username: user
  password: ''
```

Comment: have you tried this on a cedar stack? `heroku create --stack cedar`

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046092/rake-assetsprecompile-rails-env-production-error/36083793#36083793. The replies in the link  (including mine) are helpful.

Answer (score 54):

Old question but the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question - and I just found this in a search so I guess it's relevant.

The reason for the error is that `gem 'pg'` is in the production gem group.
When you run `rake assets:precompile` the production environment is accessed. So it is trying to load the production environment **but you don't have all of the dependencies installed**.

Running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails server` would probably give you a similar error.

I can think of two different solutions

1) Look to see if you have a `.bundle/config` file in your app's root. If you do, check if it says `WITHOUT :production` or similar. Either remove that line or the whole `.bundle` directory and run `bundle` again.

2) in `Gemfile`

```
gem :development, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

while removing the `:production` group
run `bundle` again

Sorry to bring up old stuff...

Comment: Sorry I accidentally downvoted you but now I cant undo it :( -- I actually found your answer useful

Comment: @SherwinYu Just click the downvote icon again and your downvote will be cancelled.

Comment: @DavidTuite unfortunately, you can't if it's been a while -- your downvote gets locked unless the answer is edited.

Comment: I just read somewhere if i edit it it can be re-upvoted @SherwinYu
Let's test this out! Thanks ChristopheHarris btw

Comment: @pferdefleisch Thanks for your answer. Solution 2) worked for me very well.