# rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

I want to deploy a spree app to heroku and in order to do that I need to precompile my assets locally 
I did

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

then I added config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

my database.yaml file is

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: anzels_development
  username: anzels
  password: 1234

test:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: anzels_test
  username: anzels
  password: 1234


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: anzels_production
  pool: 5
  password:
```

and whenever I run

```
sumeet@sumi-pc:~/anzels$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get an error
rake aborted!

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "sumeet" does not exist
/home/sumeet/anzels/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "sumeet" does not exist
/home/sumeet/anzels/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

*config/enviormenr.rb*

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

please help

Comment: Your `config/environment.rb` would be useful.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll posted my config/environment.rb

Comment: Just create a postgres role with name "sumeet"

Comment: What rails version? Also, you don't need to precompile assets for heroku - they will detect if you did and they'll precompile them for you. Please refer to documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: @adil thanks your suggestion worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In local computer  you are trying to run

> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

but this requires your local compute to have config/database.yml with the config mentioned by @thieu-nguyen

so add the following in

> username: $PRODUCTION_DB_USER
>
> password: $PRODUCTION_DB_PASS

under production in *config/database.yml*

then add the environment for you local computer as

> PRODUCTION_DB_USER=anzels
>
> PRODUCTION_DB_PASS=1234

and for heroku as

> PRODUCTION_DB_USER=user
>
> PRODUCTION_DB_PASS=""       (empty)

---

## **ANOTHER  EASIER WAY IS**

> username: anzels
>
> password: 1234

to **production** in *config/database.yml* **JUST BEFORE assests precompilation **
then run command

> git checkout config/database.yml

**JUST BEFORE GIT COMMIT command**
the idea is to not to commit the username and password but temporarily edit it for assests precompilation purpose only

Answer (score 0):

Please add `username` and `password` to production config in `database.yml` or you need to create new role for postgres with name "sumeet".

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: anzels_production
  pool: 5
  username: anzels
  password: 1234
```

Comment: production db does not have a user or password

Comment: But you want to compile assets in your local, right?

Comment: yes I do, but by doing this I get an authentication error

Comment: You just need to compile assets in your local, then push it to heroku, so just config your production config like developemnt enviroment (database name, username, pass) :)